# c++.что делает этот код?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Здравствуйте,есть данный фрагмент кода,до конца не могу понять,что он выполняет.могли бы объяснить,что он делает?
и есть ли возможность его переделать под линукс?используется библиотека windows.h

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DWORD pid;
    DWORD_PTR mask;
    HANDLE hProc;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [PID] [AFFINITY]\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    mask = atoll(argv[2]);

    printf("PID=%u, MASK=%llu\n", pid, mask);

    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    if (hProc == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening process, code=%u\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    if (!SetProcessAffinityMask(hProc, mask))
    {
        printf("Error setting affinity, code=%u\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);

    printf("Affinity adjusted.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Определяет, на каких процессорах в многопроцессорной системе может выполняться определенный процесс - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686223

Comment: "...не могу понять,что он выполняет... и есть ли возможность его переделать под линукс.."  - зачем его переделывать по линукс, если Вы не знаете, что он делает?

Comment: `windows.h` - это не библиотека, а заголовочный файл.

Answer (score 3):

Программа принимает 2 параметка - id процесса и маску ядер процессоров, на которых этот процесс должен выполняться. Она пытается установить эту маску для заданного процесса.

Консольный аналог вот этого действия из диспетчера задач:

[image: скриншот контекстного меню]
  
[image: скриншот окна]

Comment: Спасибо теперь стало понятнее,а не знаете можно ли сделать тоже самое,но на линуксе?

Comment: @Андрей, там всё уже сделано: https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset

Comment: а как его использовать в программе?

Comment: @Андрей, его использовать вместо программы. `taskset -p 12620 -c 0-3`

Comment: @Андрей, а может даже так: `taskset -p 7 12620`